# Filter value from many columns in table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I trying to create SQL question to my PostgreSQL database. I have table looks like as:

```
id | column1 | column2| column3 | column4
1  |   1     |   2    |    3    |   1
2  |   21    |   22   |    23   |   5
3  |   31    |   22   |    32   |   6
4  |   54    |   43   |    45   |   4
5  |   43    |   23   |    34   |   4
6  |   43    |   54   |    43   |   2
7  |   54    |   52   |    53   |   8
8  |   21    |   2211 |    43   |   4
9  |   43    |   33   |    45   |   9
10 |   87    |   62   |    11   |   3
```

I try to write question for return only unique value for chosen column, for example ***column1***:

```
id | column1 | column2| column3 | column4
1  |  1      |   2    |    3    |   1
2  |  21     |   22   |    23   |   5
3  |  31     |   22   |    32   |   6
8  |  21     |   2211 |    43   |   4
10 |  87     |   62   |    11   |   3
```

My request:

```
SELECT id, column1, column2, column3, column4
FROM test AS T
WHERE T.column1 != T.column2
   OR T.column1 != T.column3
```

In response, I get the entire table, not unique records.

Can someone tell me why this is not working and explain how to write a query that will work.

Comment: Think about the difference between OR and AND

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the result. If you're trying to find the rows with unique values in column1, why are 2 and 8 returned which are both 21? If you're trying to find rows where all columns are unique, why are 5 and 7 excluded?

Comment: You mean the values that don't repeat of a specific column, right?

Comment: @Marco yes, i'm trying to write a query that returns unique rows, like in the example what should my query return

Comment: Oh, you want to return rows where their column1 doesn't appear in *any* row of columms 2 or 3 or 4?

Comment: Could you explain why row 1 is allowed?

Comment: @Schwern Yes, I want an answer like in the example answer

Comment: @Schwern he/she forgot to mention that `column4` should not be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want rows where their value in column1 does not appear in any other row's column2, column3, or column4.

For this you can do a subquery to check each row against every other row.

```
select *
from test t1
where not exists (
  select id
  from test t2
  where t2.id <> t1.id and (
     t2.column2 = t1.column1 or
     t2.column3 = t1.column1 or
     t2.column4 = t1.column1
  )
)
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d57bae2a69608f7f00513f8b8fd0304e)

Note that the need to check different columns for uniqueness suggests that column1, column2, column3, and column4 are actually a list of the same type of value. It would be better to store the values a join table.

```
create table test (
  id bigserial primary key
);

create table test_stuff (
  test_id bigint not null references test,
  value integer not null
);

insert into test values (1);
insert into test_stuff values (1, 1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,1);
```

Comment: That's way clearer

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE
    COLUMN1 NOT IN (
        SELECT COLUMN2
        FROM TEST
    )
    AND COLUMN1 NOT IN (
        SELECT COLUMN3
        FROM TEST
    )
```

You can try here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmMr3vz2JHvfBabu62Si79/0

Comment: If I select column1, then there should not be such rows that contain numbers from column1, that is, numbers from column1 can be repeated, but not from 2 and 3

Comment: Now I've understood, the thing that was getting me it was your `column4`, since rowid 1 has the 1 value in both column1 and column4. Updated my answer.